# Как сравнить переменную с ключом в словаре

Tags: python

Задание такое 
Пользователем вводит логин и пароль, моя функция должна принять и проверить в словаре ( ключ - логин, значение - пароль ) если логин и пароль верный то все ок , если нет то ерор

Comment: А что не получается?

Comment: Как сравнить переменную которую введёт пользователь со списком ( в который заранее забит логин-пароль)

Comment: dict = {"login": "pass"}
if ("login" in dict and dict['login'] == 'pass'): print("success")

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот рабочий пример без `try: except:`  :

```
x = {'DGDays':'1234567890qaz'}
login = input('Введите логин: ')
password = input('Введите пароль: ')
if login in x:
    if password == x[login]:
         print('Привет, ' + login + '!!!')
    else:
         print('Пароль неверен!')
else:
    print('Неверный логин')
```

---

Вот пример с `try: except:`  :

```
x = {'DGDays':'1234567890qaz'}
login = input('Введите логин: ')
password = input('Введите пароль: ')
try:
    if password == x[login]:
        print('Привет, ' + login + '!!!')
    else:
        print('Пароль неверен!')
except KeyError:
    print('Неверный логин')
```

По сути try-except это обработчик исключений/ошибок. То есть если возникает какая-то ошибка(в моём случае KeyError), то программа выполняет команды указанные на этот случай.

Comment: А если логин будет введен неверный ? То этот код выдаст ошибку ?

Comment: В данном случае да, но могу изменить чтобы проверка шла и на логин, либо через конструкцию `try: except:`

Comment: Вот эту конструкция я ещё не прошел )

Comment: Можете пожалуйста объяснить 4 строчку , вы в ней присвоили введённый логин к ключу в словаре ? Верно?)

Comment: Наличие логина без try-except можно проверить с помощью `login in x`

Comment: @Maks, в четвёртой(теперь пятой) строке происходит сравнение пароля со значением словаря, которое имеет ключ равный login

Comment: @Maks, ответ обновил. Всё варианты есть

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь !) Я какого-то черта вообще в другую сторону ушел) очень признателен